# Dynamically hide photo galleries that have no images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script for my galleries:

```
<div class="photogallery">
  <div class="Spacer"></div>
  <div style="padding:10px 15px 0;">
    <div class="LuauPackages">
      <div class="GreenLrg" style=" display:inline-

block;vertical-align:top;">Gallery</div>
      <div class="arrow arrow-down"></div>
      <div class="arrow arrow-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="LuauPackCont">
      <asp:Literal id="litPhotos" Runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Scroll down the page where it says "Gallery" 
https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/oahu/luaus/hilton-waikiki-starlight.htm

Since this is a dynamically generated script it appears on all pages including the ones that don't have galleries such as - https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/activities/oahu/surfing/north-shore-tour.htm

My question is how can I dynamically set .photogallery {display: none} for all pages that don't have galleries?

One common thing that all pages with galleries have is the class name of each photo - bottomphotos, so is it possible to write a script that says if you don't find class called bottomphotos on the page, make .photogallery {display: none}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is roughly what you want:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  if($('.bottomphotos').length === 0) { // if you cannot find any elements with class name of bottomphotos
    $('.photogallery').hide(); // then hide the photogallery element
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only problem is it works only when I add the code inline. If I add it in one of the js files it doesn't work. I even created a separate hidegallery.js just to test this but still doesn't work.

Comment: If you try putting in a breakpoint in hidegallery.js on the line where it checks for `bottomphotos`, does it even find the `bottomphotos` HTML elements? If not, then I suspect the JS is being executed before your page is rendered. If this is the case, you might want to check out: https://api.jquery.com/ready/. I edited my answer to reflect that.